# How could check content of td without spaces and lines

Tags: html, css, django

I have a a table with dynamic value of td, some of td will be empty and some will has value, the empty td I want there background red, and filled td should be green 
I tried to do that with css by :

```
td:empty {
          background-color: red;
        }
```

the issue that I faced is empty td has only spaces & lines content that spaces make `td:empty` totally useless

in other words the css reading there is a content in td tag, but in fact that content is just spaces and lines which is fake content 
how could fix his problem ?

--- update ---
here is output result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1wd5.png
and here is the script :

```
<td>
    {% for mission in missions|get_missions_by_user:user %}
        {% if mission.start_date|date:"d-m-Y" == week_dates.6.date|date:"d-m-Y" %}
            {{ mission.title }}
             <!-- filled cell - this should be green background -->
            <br>
        {% endif %}
        <!-- empty cell - this should be red background -->
    {% endfor %}
</td>
```

Comment: Trim the content before creating the table.

Comment: You would need to use JavaScript for this, since `:empty`, as you found, considers white-space to be content.

Comment: Im not familiar with js  @ritaj

Comment: Can you show enough of your table's HTML that we can see what the 'normal' (non-empty) `<td>` elements would contain in contrast to the 'empty' cells?

Comment: I dont think this would be possible without writing any scripts

Comment: I'm sorry @dan, but we'd need to see some of the generated HTML, not the script that produces it (since we've got no reference to the `missions` variable.

Comment: This may be a dumb suggestion, but what if you remove all characters between the html and the Django code? so `<td>{% for ...` and later `... endfor %}</td>`

Comment: @DavidThomas this is the only script in page, the remaining is normal HTML, 'mission' is normal text ex : football, watch movies , reading books .. etc

Comment: I don't this this is a good solution, which I should be always at the mercy of the code arrangement @MichaelBeeson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for every body tried to help me , 
after few days of searching and asking Javascript exports I got the script

this script is an alternative way for td:empty but trimming spaces and lines

here is the js script :

```
    $("#tableID td:not(:first-child)").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0) {
            $(this).css("backgroundColor", "green");

        } else {
            $(this).css("backgroundColor", "red");


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Could adding the needed calss by [**`yesno`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) be a solution for you?

CSS:

```
td.empty {
  background-color: red;
}
td.filled {
  background-color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td class='{{missions.count|yesno:"filled,empty"}}'>
    {% for mission in missions %}
        {% if mission == 'MISSION' %}
            {{ mission }}
            <!-- filled cell - this should be green background -->
            <br>
        {% endif %}
        <!-- empty cell - this should be red background -->
    {% endfor %}
</td>
```

Note: I've never done any code with django and I'm not familiar with python. In javascript I would check for `missions.length`. I think you know what I've tried above. Hope i helps.:)

Comment: No, because the missions that passed the condition will be in 1 cell separate by <br> not in another cell , the output totally missed up

Comment: @dan ah, i understand. updated my answer. Hope this will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: great trying, but it's always return true (the whole table is green even for empty)

Comment: maybe `missions.count > 0|yesno: [...]` or something like this?

Comment: could you tell me how the object or array `missions` looks like?

Comment: it's class object contains variables ('title', 'date, 'user') I can access to any of them by  dot, ex : mission.title

Comment: But mostly I believe it's need JS script , checking all td tags, then check there contains text if content.length > 0 set css background: green, else set red background but I don't know how to do it with js

Comment: ah okay, so an empty one would look for example like {'title': '', 'date': '', user: ''} ?

Comment: could you provide some html of the rendered table? i will need `td` with values inside and one of the empty ones. (you could find this inside your browsers sourcecode). Would be nice if you add this into your question and let me know about the update. :)

Comment: In fact the script is a little bit more complicated than what I wrote, but same arrange, I will update the script as ur request

Comment: good morning @dan sorry but im looking for the rendered sourcecode not a screenshot. :)

Comment: As i can see you want to color the table head instead of the tablecell? I think this really cant be done without using javascript. If so, i dont really have an idea, since i dont know how django works. To get this done using javascript the script has to be run after the html is rendered, i dont know djangos "timing".

Comment: No worries my friends thx for help , I will take care of it , if so, I will post the answer here

Answer (score 0):

you have to add and remove class if tabld td is empty then add class and on that class you give background.